# GitHub satanically messing with Markdown - changes 666 to DCLXVI

Tags: github, markdown

[My GitHub repository](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked/tree/fa599eaee537e05657d6d73116ee8c177eeb2c50) has nothing but a readme in it. In this readme, locally I wrote this:

```
Factoids:
 - There are about six different ways to do everything in Forked.
 - There are actually six different ways to enter loops.
 - There are six directionals and six I/O commands.
 - 666. ha.
```

Emphasis on the last line.
What GitHub decided to show was *not* `666`.

[image: dclxvi]

`DCLXVI` is the Roman Numeral number for [666](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/666_(number)).

This really creeped me out. My local file and [the raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aaronryank/Forked/fa599eaee537e05657d6d73116ee8c177eeb2c50/README.md) both show `666`.

What is GitHub doing, and why is the indentation on the un-numbered list messed up? Is this an easter egg, or some satanic bug?

Comment: Did you try `- 5. whatever` it should turn into `·V whatever` if i see it correctly

Comment: Just tested myself and all numbers convert to roman numerals: https://github.com/NoahCristino/Forked/tree/48a2fd5bbbec551ab3fa67c06e3debd8071e9955

Comment: @immibis using hyphens for bullets is standard markdown isn't it?

Comment: @EdmundReed Isn't the nested list notation also standard markdown?

Comment: Don't worry about the actual Latin number, either. That number probably doesn't mean at all what the common understanding is because of a translation error.

Comment: @MDXF I thought I clearly answered and illustrated why the roman numerals was on top of the bullet point.

Comment: The new title clearly killed the mood. Why not a compromise? For instance: "GitHub satanically messing with my README (Ie. incorrectly formatting a number in a list as roman numeral)"

Comment: @VonC done something similar.

Comment: This is such a brilliant bug... all we need now is some gun ho junior tech journalist to publish an article about the GitHub 'satan virus' and we'll have a real winner!

Comment: @GrayedFox with creds to me obviously, then maybe this post can get 666 votes

Comment: OP never edited the markdown in the github repo so it still says dclxvi!

Comment: @ESR there is no such thing as "standard Markdown"

Comment: Almost 666 upvotes.

Comment: Can we all please concentrate on keeping this at 666 upvotes ...

Comment: too late, @blank, the light side has won. This is too good not to upvote.

Comment: Oh my God! Upvoting to help removing this curse.

Answer (score 495, accepted):

This seems to be followed by [github/markup issue 991](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/991), where on ordered sub-list, decimal numerals automatically turns into roman numerals.

> I have found the cause of problem. It is CSS
>
> > This is the expected way for nested ordered lists to render in HTML.
>
> This is not expected in HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/tf5jtv8s
>
> > We don't make any modifications to the default HTML behavior.
>
> ```
> ol ol,ul ol{list-style-type:lower-roman}
> ```
>
> I don't know CSS but my understanding is that this is the cause of problem. I can get expected result by disabling CSS. (I am from my mobile so I can't use browser inspector)

As mentioned in "[A formal spec for GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://githubengineering.com/a-formal-spec-for-github-markdown/)", GitHub markdown spec [GFM: GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/) is built on top of the  [CommonMark Spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.26).

And as [Tommi Kaikkonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8132914/tommi-kaikkonen) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44619303/6309), the ordered list is because of the dot following 666. See [GFM Spec section 5.2](https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items).

As mentioned in [section 6.1](https://github.github.com/gfm/#backslash-escapes), any ASCII punctuation character may be backslash-escaped, to avoid this issue.
That means:

```
- 666\. ha.
```

(as explicitly shown in [ForNeVeR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684760/fornever)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623878/6309))

That is why that `666` number is changed to roman numerals in a GitHub `README` markdown.

---

[Mike Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184226/mike-lippert) commented:

> the 1st element in that list so it should show as `i` not `dclxvi`.
> Markdown ordered lists ignore the actual number used and number sequentially, and I haven't seen a way to change that.

However, no: it shows `dclxvi`, because the generated html code is `<ol start="666">`, which is consistent with [the GFM specs](https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items):

> If the list item is ordered, then it is also assigned a start number, based on the ordered list marker"

(here, '`666`' is the ordered list marker)

Mike adds:

> > @VonC For anyone else here's another useful excerpt from VonC's doc link:
>
> "The start number of an ordered list is determined by the list number of its initial list item. The numbers of subsequent list items are disregarded."

---

> Also, why is the spacing messed up? I didn't catch that in your answer

You get an ordered list `<ol>` within an un-ordered list *item* `<li>`:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ol start="666">
      <li>ha.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

GitHub CSS rules include:

```
.markdown-body ol {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

If you put `3em`, you would get
[image: correct padding]
instead of
[image: wrong padding]

Comment: @MDXF I suspect because the number followed by a dot is transformed into an ordered list *on the same line* as an un-ordered list item (the '-'). Normally, <li> and <ol> are not supposed to be rendered on the same line...

Comment: @MDXF I have edited the answer with the exact CSS rule which cause the incorrect spacing.

Comment: Actually I think the output is either a markdown enhancement I haven't heard of, or a bug. Yes _- .666_ is an ordered sublist, HOWEVER, it is the 1st element in that list so it should show as _i_ not _dclxvi_ . Markdown ordered lists ignore the actual number used and number sequentially, and I haven't seen a way to change that.

Comment: @MikeLippert no, it shows at dclxvi, because the generated html code is `<ol start="666">`, which is consistent with https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items: "If the list item is ordered, then it is also assigned a start number, based on the ordered list marker" (here, '666' is the ordered list marker)

Comment: @user13267 Or CMXCI

Comment: @VonC Thanks, I hadn't known that enhancement for github-flavored markdown, and didn't find it w/ quick googling before I commented. For anyone else here's another useful excerpt from VonC's doc link _"The start number of an ordered list is determined by the list number of its initial list item. The numbers of subsequent list items are disregarded."_

Answer (score 389):

Adding a period after `666` makes it [an ordered list marker](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.26/#ordered-list-marker).

GitHub declares CSS that renders ordered list markers using roman numerals:

```
ol ol,ul ol {
    list-style-type: lower-roman
}
```

Escape the period with a backslash, and you should see the correct output.

Answer (score 89):

While other answers are good at explaining *why* you have the problem, they haven't given you an exact example of how to *fix* that.

And it seems that you've already solved it [in an imperfect manner](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked/commit/8c5c433c019ba026deb214ee4fbc8aa895fa935e), replacing your text with

```
- `666`. ha.
```

There's a common trick to escape the dot after the number to make it look like a normal text (and not an ordered list label):

```
- 666\. ha. (this will render as you probably want)
```